# Calculate total assets in a lnd

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

How can I calculate my total assets in a lnd? Something like the sum of "wallet confirmed", "wallet pending", "channels local balance", "channels pending local balance" etc.
But still, there are some voliatile amounts "locked" in commit_fee reserveres.

Without that sum, I can never make out my income (because it's dust small).